# cant access nextcloud internally with domain

Tags: nextcloud

I Install and configure NextCloud on that server. Everything is working good. I Setup HTTPS redirection and it is working perfectly when I am outside my home. But, the thing is if I access my cloud thru my domain domain name, (cloud.mydomain com) at home I cant do it access it. if I open the browser and type https:_cloud_mydomain_com it never get to anywhere. but If I type the local ip address in the address bar of the NextCloud Server it opens perfectly.

I can ping my domain from home and reply with my Modem/Public IP. I can open the NextCloud using the hostname of the Ubuntu Server or the local Ip Address of the Server but not if I use the https:_cloud.mydomain.com.

So, is wierd to me because I can access it using the domain (https:_cloud.mydomain.com) when I am off the local network. either my mobile phone or a computer. but it is annoying to every time I get home remove the domain name and login with my local ip address. https:_local_ip

The Same thing happend with the Ajenti. I setup the Ajenti, change the default port. are able to access the Ajenti out of my local network with https://cloud.mydomain.com:1234 {port} but if I try to go at home I can I have to type https:_local_ip:1234 or https:_hostname:1234

Answer (score 0):

I have also struggled with this issue. This problem is likely due to your router not properly handling the traffic. Cloud.domain.tld resolves to your public IP address, so when you request that address from your local network, the router does not know how to respond. The best solution would be to enable Hairpin NAT in your router's configuration page.
If that is impossible, you might be able to set your search domain to the bare domain (domain.tld) and set the hostname on the nextcloud server to cloud so local devices automatically resolve the IP.
You could also proxy your traffic outside of your network with a free Cloudflare account.